# Cycle 2 "Loading" background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-cycle2

Im trying to add a loading now gif to my cycle 2 plugin. How do i force the gif to load before the images load?

Currently i have my loading.gif as a background image. Problem is the loading.gif isn't loading  first

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Cycle2 API page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/), the `loader` option and [the associated demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/loader.php). In summary:

- Set `data-cycle-loader="wait"` on the slideshow div. This pauses the slideshow until all images are loaded.
- Set the background of the slideshow div to display the loading gif. Use CSS to center this image. Here is the rule used in the above mentioned demo:

---

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    background: url(http://malsup.github.com/images/spinner.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```